# JSON decoder stops after roughly 1000 iterations

Tags: python, mysql, json

I wrote a small programm that iterates over 1500 JSON files, parses them and inserts the records in a MySQL database.
But after roughly 1000 iterations my python script stops with the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/myprogram/main.py", line 107, in <module>
    exec(open("/home/ubuntu/myprogram/subprogramthatscalled.py").read())
  File "<string>", line 32, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I double checked all the JSON files and found no errors.

Here is the code I used:

```py
path = "/home/ubuntu/mypath"
path_list = os.listdir(path)

for file in path_list:
        if file.startswith("stuff") and file.endswith(".json"):
                each_file = path + file
                json_file = open(each_file)
                json_eingelesen = json.load(json_file)
                json_objects = len(json_eingelesen['data']['children'])
                for k in range(json_objects):
                        keys = ""
                        values = ""
                        for (k, v) in json_eingelesen['data']['children'][k]['data'].items():
                                keys += str(k) + ", "
                                #here was some little code to prepare kinds of variables
                                values += "'" + str(v) + "', "
                        keys = keys[:-2]
                        values = values[:-2]
                        query = "INSERT INTO reddit_subreddit_posts (%s) VALUES (%s)"%(keys, 
                        values) #I know that SQLinjection is easy here but my raspberry is 
                                 not available from outside my network, Ill secure that later
                        queries.execute(query)
                        mydb.commit()
                os.remove(each_file)
```

**Now the fun part:**
When I restart the script it runs without an error.

**So my question is:**
Are there any restrictions stopping the python JSONDecoder or any other part of my code from iterating over the rest of the JSON files?

Here are the inital bytes in hex:
7b 22 6b 69 6e 64 22 3a

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show the initial _bytes_ of the file that fails.

Comment: Strange, they seem to be fine - the first  character  is `{`.  Those bytes were definitely from the failing file?

Comment: Yes, I used the `try: ... except: continue` statement from the answer and this file was the only one left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `try ... except` mechanism to your code-line `json.load(json_file)` in order to catch these errors.

Probably, the data in `json_file` variable is not a JSON string in one of your files.

Comment: This seemed to work. Although I am able to inspect the files that has been jumped over by the `except: continue` statement afterwards. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You probably won't see the error in the file because it is invisible.

The error at character 0, so most likely it is a BOM character.

Byte-Order Mark, which is inserted by some text editors when saving UTF8 files.

You can edit the file to remove the BOM, or set encoding to 'utf-8-sig' when opening the file.

```
json_file = open(each_file, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Comment: Thank you for that answer, very interesting! I will integrate it in my code and see if files keep being skipped.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work in my script. Now it just skips each file I would like to load.